# In ImageChops.Difference(), are the pixels of two image subtracted?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to know the math behind the `ImageChops.Difference()` and how the pixels of the two images are evaluated. Thank you.

```
image1 = Image.open("img1.jpg")
image2 = Image.open("img2.jpg")
diff= ImageChops.difference(image1, image2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`ImageChops.difference(image1, image2)`**

Returns the absolute value of the difference between the two images.

```
diff = abs(image1 - image2)
```

[ImageChops Module Handbook](https://python.developpez.com/cours/pilhandbook/php/imagechops.php)

For example:

```
image1 = Image.open("img1.jpg")
image2 = Image.open("img2.jpg")

diff= ImageChops.difference(image1, image2)
#diff = abs(image1 - image2)
```

Comment: Here's more up-to-date [ImageChops documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageChops.html).

Comment: I am so grateful. Thank you